# Series $f(p)$ is a multiple of $p$

Tags: combinatorics

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: How to proof (using combinatorial proof)

Let $f(p)(p>2\text{: prime number})$ ;
$$f(p)=1^p+2^p+3^p+\cdots+(p-1)^p$$

then $f(p)$ is a multiple of $p$

Comment: Not true for $p=2$

Comment: @ccorn I think $f(p)$ is a power of $p$ instead?

Comment: No it's not. Nevermind.

Comment: oh! sorry $p>2$

Comment: Now that $p>2$: Must it be purely combinatorial, without reduction modulo $p$? Because modulo $p$, it's just pairwise cancellation, just consider the *least absolute remainders*.

Comment: Consequently, the statement holds for any odd integer $p$, not just primes $p>2$

Comment: Is this approach _purely_ combinatorial: $(1+2+\dots+(p-1))^p = 1^p + 2^p + \dots + (p-1)^p + p\times(\cdots)$

Comment: @FeiGao I like that, and you could possibly translate it into a counting argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for all ODD integer p , not just primes. Let p be an odd positive integer, not necessarily prime. To see this write in reverse ,

$$f(p) = (p-1)^p + (p-2)^p + (p-3)^p + ... + 3^p + 2^p + 1^p$$

$$ \\ f(p) = (pq_1-1^p)+(pq_2-2^p)+ ...+(pq_{ \frac{p-1}{2}} - (\frac{p-1}{2})^p) + ( \frac{p-1}{2})^p + ... + 2^p + 1^p $$

In other words f(p) will have an even number of terms and every non multiple of p cancels nicely.

Comment: Typo: The $\frac{p-1}{2}q_{(p-1)/2}$ must be $p\,q_{(p-1)/2}$.

Comment: You're absolutely right , fixing it now , thanx. :)

Comment: -1 I down voted because OP asked for a combinatorial proof, instead of an algebraic proof. This could also be better expressed (like there wasn't a need to write in reverse).

Comment: I counted an even number of terms and my presentation shows this nicely IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

There exists an easy algebraic / number theoretic proof for $p$ being an odd number. This solution is a combinatorial approach for $p$ being a **prime number**. (I would like to see an approach where $p$ is any odd number.)

A (naive) understanding of $i^p$, is that it is the number of functions from $[p] = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, p\}$ to $[i] = \{ 1, 2, \ldots , i \}$. Thus, we take the interpretation that the quantity in question is simply the number of functions (counted with repetition) from $[p]$ to $[i]$ as $i$ ranges from 1 to $p-1$.

Given any non-constant function from $[p]$ to $[i]$, there is a clear bijection with $p$ functions (inclusive of itself), by applying the shift function successively. This uses the fact that $p$ is prime. Hence, the number of such functions is a multiple of $p$.

It remains to count the number of constant functions from $[p]$ to $[i]$. There are clearly $i$ of them. Hence, the total number of constant functions is

$$1 + 2 + \ldots + (p-1) = \frac{p(p-1)}{2}$$

Now, since $p$ is odd,this number is a multiple of $p$.

Thus, $ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^p$ is a multiple of $p$.